# Get yticks back on twinned y-axis with deactivated grid in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting lines on a subplot where each of the subplots has a twinned y-axis.
The problem is that using the following matplotlib style-sheet creates automated horizontal grids for both of the twinned vertical (y-)axes, which mismatch.

```
# * Set the matplotlib.pyplot default template (plotting style and background) *
mpl_plt_default_template = 'seaborn-whitegrid'
plt.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)
```

The initial output graphic looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, two grids are generated which don't overlap.

I tried to turn off the grid of the twinned axis (on the right hand side) while making
visible the yaxis-ticks, but so far no avail.

The code I used is this:

```
# * Standard procedure of making the axis-ticks visible
# 1) Making ticks visible generally
ax.yaxis.majorTicks[0].tick1line.set_visible(True)
# 2) More in-depth tick-handling via the "runtime configuration parameters" ("rc params")
# of matplotlib
plt.rcParams.update({
    "ytick.direction": "out",  # direction: in, out, or inout
    "ytick.minor.visible": False,  # visibility of minor ticks on y-axis
    "ytick.major.left": True,   # draw y axis left major ticks
    "ytick.major.right": True   # draw y axis right major ticks
})

# i) Y-axis on the right-hand side
if twinned_axis:
    # NOTE on scope: Set left to False, right to True
    plt.rcParams.update({
        'ytick.left': False,
        "ytick.labelleft": False,
        'ytick.right': True,
        "ytick.labelright": True
    })
# ii) Standard case: y-axis on the left-hand side
else:
    # NOTE on scope: Set right to False, left to True
    plt.rcParams.update({
        'ytick.left': True,
        "ytick.labelleft": True,
        'ytick.right': False,
        "ytick.labelright": False
        })
```

The result I got can be seen in the following picture.
Unfortunately, the ticks are still missing, only the labels are visible on the twinned axis.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the problem of twinned axis, in `seaborn-whitegrid` template ticks' size is set to 0.0, check it [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ae764aefc4f5e3c5bacafd70b0a195028e0b3aba/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/seaborn-whitegrid.mplstyle#L21-L30). So, you need to change its size in `rcParams`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mpl_plt_default_template = 'seaborn-whitegrid'
plt.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)

# set size value for major ticks
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 5
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 5

f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim((0.25, 1.5))

# turn off the twinned grid
ax2.yaxis.grid(False)
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I was working with all sorts of rcParams except those you mentioned. I knew it must have been based on the default matplotlib template which defines several rcParams. I also found out, that I need to redefine the parameters before instantiating the new figure, since a rcParams change afterwards in this case doesn't take effect when there is already a line plotted (at least that's what I concluded from trial and error).